# AWS Lambda: File once required is not reloaded during second invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using a local variable within the lambda handler to store functions defined in another file. This works fine during the first invocation. But during the second invocation, the functions and variables defined in the file are taken from memory without loading for the second time. I have imported the files inside the lambda handler instead of the execution context for my use-case

```
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    ...
    const allergy_service = require('../services/allergy/allergy_service');
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to explicitly reload the required file during all lambda invocations. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Lambdas are re-used, and the result of a `require` statement is cached. Why do you want this, because it feels like really bad design to try and circumvent this.

Comment: i am curious to know the use case to re-load an entire file, instead of calling a method with in that? can you show what the content of allergy_service is?